# Not committing a transaction side effect

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a MySQL transaction that continuously runs in a loop every second and does the following:

1. BEGIN
2. SELECT ... FOR UPDATE LIMIT 100;

- application code early returns if (2) returns 0 rows

3. UPDATE SET ....
4. COMMIT

I am not explicitly closing the transaction when I early return in step 2. Are there any side effects I should be concerned about? I shouldn't be holding on to any locks because the SELECT did not return any rows.
Do I need to be concerned about these unclosed transactions building up on the database somewhere? Do they timeout automatically?

Comment: When you say "MySQL transaction" do you mean a procedure/function that runs in the engine itself or an external process? External drivers/apps tend to have implicit transaction demarcation (i.e. automatic commit/rollback).

Answer (score 1):

This is going to cause you grief.

When you return early in step 2, you really really need to send a `ROLLBACK;` command.

When you do not send the `ROLLBACK` instruction, MySQL will keep the table locked, especially if a great many rows were updated. This will cause `SELECTs`, `INSERTs`, `UPDATEs`, `DELETEs` to block, leading to bad performance.

Eventually, if your program keeps the connections open, you can hit transaction limits and your code will start blowing up, usually about 1,000 "hung" transactions.  See https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/05/08/chasing-a-hung-transaction-in-mysql-innodb-history-length-strikes-back/

Comment: I only early return if the SELECT returned 0 rows. In that case, would the table still be locked? I can see the concern about hung transactions though. Also, is there a difference between rollback vs commit when I early return?

Comment: I would also add that the fact that the for update select query does not return any rows does not mean it does not lock records. See https://mysqlquicksand.wordpress.com/2019/12/20/select-for-update-on-non-existent-rows/

Comment: yes, there will still be locks; SELECT FOR UPDATE doesn't lock the rows returned, it locks the index values/gaps needed to find those rows.